# d3 donut chart multy ring with text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I create a multi ring donut chart following some examples on the web and everything was ok till i try to display text into the ring and got stuck with different errors. 
I think at this point i can access data but i when comes to create rings, i got NaN values for my path and text.

Here is my code:

```
var dataset = {
  ringOne: [{"label":"70%", "value":70}, 
            {"label":"10%", "value":10}, 
            {"label":"20%", "value":20}],

  ringTwo: [{"label":"70%", "value":70}, 
            {"label":"10%", "value":10}, 
            {"label":"20%", "value":20}],
};


var width = 460,
    height = 300,
    cwidth = 45,
    outerR = 100,
    color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#07e", "#00aced", "#e32"]);

var svgDonut = d3.select("#donut")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")" );

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var rings = svgDonut.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie([dataset]))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "slice");

    rings.append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return color(i); })
        .attr("d", function(d, i, j){ return arc.innerRadius( 80 + cwidth * j )
                                            .outerRadius( outerR * (j) )(d); });

    rings.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {                    
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = outerR;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";        
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d, i) { return dataset.ringOne[i].label; });
```

The error i get is:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M4.898587196589413e-15,-80A80,80 0 1,1 NaN,NaNL0,0Z"
Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/anaketa/8u7gejjc/

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide fiddle link :) It will be much easier to find a bug ... First clue from me is, youre wrong set *arc* variable, because it returns NaN instead of proper values :) Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170899/arc-centroid-returning-nan-nan-in-d3 can be helpfull

Comment: You are right! Just added!

Comment: Well, i think my main problem is how i access to my data. Infact if you console.log you see data{ value: NaN} :/ But i try all the combination i know and cannot find the right way!

Comment: If i change .data(pie([dataset])) with .data(pie(dataset.ringOne)) i can see a pie carth with text. But i miss the second ring in this way :(

Comment: Are you sure .data(pie( takes and object with two datasets? Iam pretty sure you want first pie and donut chart over the original pie chart, but Iam not sure if you will be able to do that without creating one more chart...

Comment: no, i'm not sure at all :) i'm pretty new to d3. So you are suggesting to create 2 charts? a pie one and a donut one on top of the pie? Could work.. But then, can i keep same color and color position?

Comment: I am pretty new to :) Yes, my suggest is to create 2 charts. What about position and color, probably yes, but are you sure you will be able to see the border between two charts ? :)